# Tiny mail notifications?

Tags: macos, email, gmail, notifications

Is there a way to get notified if I have new gmail messages near clock on top right side of screen (menu panel you call it)? Then clicking on it will take me to browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [**Notify**](http://vibealicious.com/apps/notify/),

> If you access your email in a browser, you'll love Notify.  Notify is an awesome email notifier for Mac OS X. It fits seamlessly into your menubar, only vying for your attention when you have new mail. Notify supports mutliple accounts, including Gmail/Google Apps, MobileMe, and Rackspace Email. All in a beautiful interface.

Also see, [Top 10 Great Gmail Notifiers for Windows and Mac](http://tutorial.downloadatoz.com/top-10-great-gmail-notifiers-for-windows-and-mac.html).
There is a [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_mac.html) from [Google](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=46078) too.

Answer (score 1):

[MacBiff](http://macbiff.sourceforge.net/) is free, open source, and highly customizable. It will notify you itself, or you can pipe new mail alerts to external programs, for example, growlnotify or "say" so that new mail is announced verbally.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Notify, mentioned in the top-rated answer, is no longer supported by the developer. The best replacement I've found is [Mail Call](https://mailcallapp.com/) - it works with any mail provider that supports IMAP. For GMail alone, there's also [Mia](https://www.miaforgmail.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try Webmail Notifier which is a Mozilla plugin.

- Gmail (Gmail & Google Apps)
- Yahoo (yahoo.com, ymail.com, yahoo.co.jp)
- Hotmail (hotmail.com, msn.com, live.com)
- AOL (aol.com, aim.com, mail.com)
- Daum (daum.net, hanmail.net)
- Naver
- Nate (nate.com, empas.com)
- Paran (paran.com, hanmir.com)
- POP3/IMAP

http://webmailnotifier.mozdev.org/